# can my 15-year-old brother leave the UK to go back to his home country without being accompanied by the stated accompanied person in his UK visa?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, minors

My younger brother, who is 15, is going to visit me in the UK with my dad as the adult accompanying him. But my dad is only going for two weeks and my brother will go back 2 weeks after him. They are coming from Indonesia.

My question is, will they let him board the plane to go back to Indonesia? Since there will be no immigration exiting the UK, I presume that there won't be any problem?

I will be sending him off to the airport until he gets on the plane.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be leaving but staying for two weeks without the accompanying adult. It could be asked whether your dad will be allowed to leave without the minor he is supposed to be accompanying.

Comment: What was the basis of the visa application? Did it state that your father would be leaving the UK before your brother or were the visit dates provided in the application the same for both? If the latter, it’s not impossible they will be questioned on arrival in the UK and your brother’s visit could be curtailed to match your father’s.

Comment: Why not an unaccompanied minor visa? It seems more appropriate for the described plan.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I have just called the UKVI regarding this (had to pay for it, of course) but the UKVI said that the adult stated on the visa has to accompany my brother from the start of the trip until the end, i.e. my dad will have to get on the plane with my brother to go back to Indonesia. And the reason why he can't get unaccompanied minor visa is because Indonesian and East Timor citizens are not allowed to have unaccompanied minors entering the UK.

Comment: was reluctant to call the UKVI but had to since my dad was about to buy the flight tickets